# How to show and hide fieldset content on click of the legend

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I have a html page as below,
[image]
the tags code is :

```
<fieldset>
          <legend>Tags</legend>
          <div>
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="col" value="summary" checked="checked" />
                Name
              </label>
                  ......
                   </div>
        </fieldset>
```

But i want to make the page as below:
[image]

In this screenshot, when i click the Columns, it will be fold and the tags invisible. Any one know how to do this? Add a CSS or JS? Thanks

Comment: > Use jquery toggle function to show and hide that feildset
> http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know is not fieldset, but its design is looking exactly as the one you posted, so I guess this makes the trick. The code below is what you'r looking for, and some explanations about it are below the code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#title').click(function(){
         $('#tags_check').toggle();
      });
   })
</script>

<style type="text/css">
   #content {
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
   }

   #title {
      border: 1px solid grey;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #ccc;
      top: -5px;
      left: 15px;
      z-index: 1;
      cursor: pointer;
   }

   #tags_check {
      border: 1px solid grey;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 0;
      top: 3px;
      padding: 5px;
   }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">
   <div id="title">Columns</div>
   <div id="tags_check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="col" value="summary" checked="checked" /> Name1
      <input type="checkbox" name="col" value="summary" checked="checked" /> Name2
   </div>
</div>  
</body>
```

I'm using jquery, because is incredible easier than writtingh any other javascript, and I'm loading the library via CDN. As you see, show or hide is pretty easy, just when the document is loaded, toggle between both states, show or hide. I include the ID of the elements (as you can see I changed the layout) to pick them up easily.

About the desing, with fieldset... is going to be complicated achieve what you posted. Better just two divs, 'position: relative' to move them easily up and down. The CSS shows z-index to put one over the oter, and this only work on relative and absolute elements, along the top and left properties. Hope you like it!

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by first finding all of the `legend` elements, then assigning an `onclick` handler. The handler is assigned to the first `div` found in the legend's parent. So this will work even if you have multiple fieldsets and legends on the same page.

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UHn6q/1/)**

```
window.onload = function(){

    var legends = document.getElementsByTagName("legend");

    for(var i=0; i<legends.length; i++)
    {
        legends[i].onclick = function()
        {
            var myDivs = this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div");
            var myDiv;

            if(myDivs.length > 0)
            {
                var myDiv = myDivs[0];

                if(myDiv.style.display == "")
                {
                    myDiv.style.display = "none"
                }
                else
                {
                    myDiv.style.display = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }

};
```

​
In the demo, I also added CSS to the legend `cursor:pointer;`, which just shows the hand when you hover over the legend (to indicate to click).

Comment: should be `myDiv.style.display = "none"` instead of `myDiv.style.display = ""`?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the legend using CSS like you do for any other html element. Using Jquery is very simple, just have to do something like this:

#### Jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $('legend').click(function(){  
        $(this).nextAll('div').toggle();
        $(this).hasClass('hide')?($(this).attr("class", "show")):($(this).attr("class", "hide"));
    });
})​
```

#### CSS:

```
.hide{
    padding-left: 10px;
    background: url('img/down.gif') no-repeat left middle;
}

.show:after{
    padding-left: 10px;
    background: url('img/up.gif') no-repeat left middle;
}
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bzAkL/1/)**